# How can I call an instance function?

Tags: python

I have a class instance and I would like to call one of the instance functions

```
udp_action = UDPActions( application = self.application )
func = getattr( udp_action, 'udp_' + opts['cmd'] + '_fired' )
```

but I'm getting the following error

```
Values instance has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Where do I make the mistake?

Comment: What is `opts`?  You probably need to paste more code to get helpful answer.

Comment: Actually it is an object and I used as a dictionary, that was the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `opts` as if it were a dictionary (or a dictionary-like object), but it isn't.

It doesn't support the `['cmd']` notation, resulting in the exception you're seeing.

```
In [1]: class Values(object): pass

In [2]: opts = Values()

In [3]: opts['cmd']

TypeError: 'Values' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```